# OpenCV crashes when calling findcontours UWP

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dll, uwp

I am trying to create a .dll which should run on the HoloLens later. For now it just runs on an UWP Application. I encountered a problem which just occurs when im not removing the "findContours" line. I already tried to build it for Release Build, but it doesn't find the .dlls anymore because i use the OpenCV-HoloLens NuGet-Package to get it to work but it seems like there are just Debug .dlls. The data can't be corrupted or empty because the Canny algorithm wouldn't work either giving a normal result.

C++ .dll Code:

```
cvtColor(datamat, gray, COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);

blur(gray, gray, Size(3, 3));
Canny(gray, canny, 50, 200);

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(canny.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Error from the Debugging of the UWP Application which uses the dll:
[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem once. I was using Unreal Engine with using a .lib version of some code of mine (which used OpenCV). Turned out since the Unreal Engine has a garbage collector it had a problem with the way the vectors were being used. Maybe it's the same problem? Are you sure you are using the dll and not the .lib?

Comment: I don't know how to check that. What did you do to get it to work? I tried it with only adding the .dlls to the proj as well

Comment: You can try to remove the dlls, if the code still run, then you compiled the with the libs, otherwise you are using the dll.

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work without the dlls

Comment: Thanks for your help, i found the problem. I'll write an answer for anyone else who has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the problem:
I already read that on some answers the problem was the build for Debug. The problem why I couldn't build for Release was that in the settings -> Linker -> General the "Additional libraries" or how it is called in english was only set for Debug Mode.

Just copy this setting from debug to release and it will work for Release and the dll can be used without a problem :) I hope this helps anyone.